# Symfony2 imbricate sql request

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two objects: Employe and Realisation

In objet Realisation we have attribut employe and type.
Now , i want to select some employes who made some realisations.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT e FROM MonBundle:Employe e WHERE e IN ( SELECT DISTINCT r.employe FROM MonBundle:Realisation r WHERE
r.type = :type)";
$query = $em->createQuery($sql);
$query->setParameter("type",$type);
```

> ==>Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression

Comment: why not simply `SELECT DISTINCT r.employe FROM MonBundle:Realisation r WHERE
r.type = :type` ?

Comment: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the relation between your entity Employe and Realisation should be a One-To-One bidirectional or One-To-many bidirectional

you can see how it work here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional

with this, you can have access to all the Linked Data has your entity

Then you can use a JOIN in your query to link your Employe to one or many Realisation (depends the relation type between your 2 entities) and do something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT e
FROM MonBundle:Employe e
JOIN e.realisation r
WHERE r.type = :type
```

to get a list of Employees who have a realisation with type = ?

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins

Comment: there is not field named realisation in object employe

Comment: @krome Welcome to stack overflow; please bear in mind that it may help to provide explanation in your answer of what `JOIN` does and how it works, as it may help the asker of the question to more effectively apply it and will also help future visitors to the website who may not understand what this `JOIN` does from only the code in your answer.

Comment: Thank you soo much